# Programming on different ARM architectures

Tags: python, linux, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to be sure I understand some basics about programming for different ARM architectures (e.g. ARMv5 vs ARMv7).

I have a python program that was ported to the newer Raspberry Pi B(Cotrex-7A). What would it take to also have it run on an ARMv6 or ARMv5 architecture. The program does simple waveform processing and serial communication with no need for a GPU.

My understanding is that I would have to recompile the program for each of the architectures to account for the different instruction sets. And I would also need to run the same version of Linux (in this case Wheezy), but is there more I have to consider here?

Is there the possibility that if it compiles in an ARMv7 it won't on an ARMv6 or ARMv5

Thanks

Comment: often you can compile for the older architecture and have it work on the newer, they generally add and rarely if ever remove.   for normal instructions that is true, for floating point it is on a chip by chip basis as to what you have, if you use soft float you are portable, hard float is where problems can arise (again old probably ports so long as you dont go really old).

Comment: For fun, you could also phrase this as "I have a Python program that works on my Core i5, what would it take to also have it run on a Core 2 Duo/Pentium 4/Pentium III/Quark?" and the answers would be pretty much identical. If you're coming from x86 and have never had to worry about the architecture versions there, then chances are you're unlikely to run into significant issues on ARM either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about python is that you rarely need to worry about the
underlying architecture.  Python is interpreted, so the interpreter does
all the hard work of handling 32 bit, 64 bit, little-endian, big-endian,
soft or hard floating point etc.

Also, you don't need to compile your python, as the interpreter will
also compile your source if your provide both the .py and the .pyc or .pyo file
and the latter does not match what is needed. Compiling python is
not the same as compiling C, for example, as python targets a virtual
machine, not real hardware.  The resulting .pyc or .pyo files are
however tied to the particular version of python.

Generally, source files are usually provided, and if there is no .pyc or .pyo for them,
then the first time python is run it will create them (if it has
file permissions). A second run will then use the compiled versions,
if the source has not changed.

Comment: Great, Thanks! I am fairly new to both python and ARM development so this pointed me in the right direction.  I assume my main constraints will be python version compatibilities